# How to calculate the standard error of multiple linear regression coefficient

Tags: mathematical-statistics, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, standard-error

I'm learning linear regression.  I'm stuck on how to calculate the standard error of the coefficients.  I know that in the simple linear regression provided by this equation $ y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x + \varepsilon$ is:
\begin{align}
SE(\hat\beta_0)^2 &= \sigma^2 \left( \frac{1}{n} + \frac{\bar{x}^2}{\sum^{i = 1}_{n} (x_i - \bar{x})^2} \right )  \\[5pt]
SE(\hat\beta_1)^2 &= \frac{\sigma^2}{\sum^{i = 1}_n (x_i - \bar{x} ) ^2}  
\end{align}

Given that $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the error term ($\,\varepsilon\,$)

But when the model is extended to $k$ variables ($y = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_1 + \beta_2x_2 + ... + \beta_kx_k + \varepsilon$), can we have a general formula to calculate each $SE(\hat\beta_i)$ (given that all the model assumption about the data is correct)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get a general formula for a multiple regression coefficient standard error, you need to use linear (matrix) algebra.  The formula for the variance-covariance matrix of the betas is:
$$
VCOV(\hat{\beta}) = s^2{\bf (X'X)^{-1}}
$$
From there, you take the positive square root of the $j^{\rm th}$ diagonal element to get the standard error of that beta.

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm kinda confused. What would happen when X is not invertible here pls?

Comment: @Miku, if X is not invertible, then the model cannot be fit, so you won't have to worry about the SE.

Comment: I read about the matrix that you mentioned here, https://www.sciencedirect.com/topics/mathematics/variance-covariance-matrix . Does it make more sense cause $X^TX$ will always be invertible ?

Comment: @Miku, if it's not invertible, you won't have a model. If you have a model, then the matrix was invertible. Inverting the matrix is part of the process of fitting the model.

Comment: Ohh thank you, I got it now :D

Comment: You're welcome, @Miku.

Comment: @Miku $\hat\beta = (X'X)^{-1}X'y$, which is why it must be that $X'X$ is invertible.

Comment: @Gung Isn't it the case the model *still* can be fit when $X$ is rank deficient?  Although the fit is no longer unique, *certain combinations of parameters might still be determined* -- the "estimable" ones.  These facts would seem to contradict your previous comments.

Comment: Might be helpful to add that this formula assumes homoskedastic (non-spherical) errors. It would be wrong under heteroskedasticity and/or autocorrelation.

Comment: This formula relies on all the standard regression assumptions.  It would be wrong if the errors are not independent, if they aren't homoscedastic, or if they aren't normal.

Comment: Normality is not needed.

Comment: You're right, the SE can be fine if the errors aren't normal, but confidence intervals and p-values can be wrong.